# Почему не выводит false?

Tags: javascript

Переменные, объявленные в не строгом режиме, удалять нельзя

```
var a = {p: 2};
console.log(delete a);
```

Код выводит true в Mozilla Firebug, а в Chrome false(то есть правильно), почему?

Comment: В мозилле для разработчиков, все правильно работает...

Comment: Где его скачать?

Comment: https://www.mozilla.org/ru/firefox/developer/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все дело в том , что firebug Firefox интепретирует все как ECMAScript 6, а там свои приколы

Comment: С `delete` там не добавилось приколов. Только в плане переменных, объявленных с помощью `let` и `const`.

Answer (score 1):

Зачем вообще делать то, что делать нельзя, и сравнивать результаты?

Такая конструкция запрещена в строгом режиме не просто так.

Можешь попробовать нормальное `delete window.a`.

Answer (score 0):

Это в строгом режиме нельзя применять оператор delete к переменным. В нестрогом режиме это можно делать.

> NOTE When a delete operator occurs within **strict mode code**, a
>   SyntaxError exception is thrown if its UnaryExpression is a direct
>   reference to a variable, function argument, or function name. In
>   addition, if a delete operator occurs within strict mode code and the
>   property to be deleted has the attribute { [[Configurable]]: false },
>   a TypeError exception is thrown.

Comment: А почему результаты разные в разных браузерах?

Comment: @LEQADA А когда результаты в разных браузерах были одинаковы?:)

Comment: Хороший аргумент )

Answer (score 0):

`delete` разрешён для `"use strict"` не для всех операций:

```
var a = {x: 0};
delete a.x;
```

Сработает.

А вот `delete Object.prototype` нет, как и:

```
var a = {x: 0};
delete a
```

нет.

P.S. В версиях Internet Explorer до Internet Explorer 10 строгий режим не поддерживается.

Список поддерживаемых браузеров смотрите [тут](http://caniuse.com/#feat=use-strict):

```
_______________________________________________________________________________________________________
| IE  | Edge | Firefox | Chrome | Safari | Opera | iOS Safari | Android Browser | Chrome  for android |
| 10+ |  12+ |    40+  |   43+  |   8+   |  32 + |    8.4+    |        4.1+     |         46          |
```

---

Для хрома попробуйте так:

```
(function()
{
    'use strict';
    var a = {p: 2};
    console.log(delete a);
}());
```

Comment: А почему результаты разные в разных браузерах?

Comment: @LEQADA ну, например в в версиях Internet Explorer до Internet Explorer 10 строгий режим не поддерживается.

Comment: Список поддерживаемых браузеров тут http://caniuse.com/#feat=use-strict

Comment: Ок, ну почему тогда в Chrome -  false а в Mozzila - true?

Comment: @Suvitruf, по ссылке видно, что поддержка есть и в Chrome и в Firefox. А результаты разные.

Comment: @LEQADA какие версии используете?

Comment: @Suvitruf, Chrome - 46, FF - 42

Comment: самые новие  версии )

Comment: @LEQADA я обновил ответ, попробуйте заключить код в function и проверить.

Comment: @Suvitruf, `SyntaxError: Delete of an unqualified identifier in strict mode`

Comment: @LEQADA так и должно быть.

Comment: Всьоравно я не мог удалять определьонную с var глобальную переменную, так кныга пишет

Comment: @Suvitruf, мне кажется, что вопрос ТС остался открытым. JS всё же штука кроссбраузерная. То есть, не нужно её менять для разных браузеров. Есть стандарты. А тут вот такая ситуация. Может баг?

Comment: @LEQADA с чего вы взяли, что из кроссбраузерности вытекает то, что код должен работать одинаково? Спецификация языка одинаковая, но вот JS движок у браузеров разный.

Comment: што ето ТС?))))

Comment: @Suvitruf, движок делается по стандартам, нет? Так почему простейшая функция (?) возвращает два разных значения в разных браузерах последних версий?

Comment: Получается што "if(delete object) показать блок на сайте" в одном браузере покажется а в другом нет?

Comment: @LEQADA потому что спецификация не описывает досконально всё. При реализации бывает разногласия, поэтому многие вещи и по-разному работают. По-этому многие и используют jQuery.

Comment: @Suvitruf, что значит "всё ещё разрешён"?

Comment: @dzhioev ну вон, для полей же работает `delete a.x`

Comment: @Suvitruf, фразу "все еще разрешен" можно истолковать так, будто кто-то собирался его запретить.

Comment: @dzhioev для объектов же запретили удаление)

Comment: @Suvitruf, фраза "что-то все еще разрешено" подразумевает, что были попытки это что-то запретить, или есть основания полагать, что это что-то будет вскоре запрещено.